# Parsing a shortcode through an author meta textfield

Tags: shortcode, user-meta, profiles

I have been using the [UPME plugin](http://profileplugin.com/) to design a member profile website that allows me to take information and show each user different profiles depending on a shortcode I put into a textarea field.

The problem I am having is using the `do_shortcode` call in my `functions.php`.  I am not 100% sure if the field is being called correctly.  I know it's not working as the shortcode is not loading anything up, but I do know the name of the textarea field is definitely `view_matches`.

Here is what I have so far `print do_shortcode(the_author_meta( 'view_matches' ));`

Comment: check if the output of the the_author_meta( 'view_matches' ) has a valid shortcode in it?

Comment: Hey there MortalViews, thanks for your answer, but I tried that with a working shortcode, just a basic line break and it was still showing just the shortcode and not the output of the shortcode.

Comment: the output of the_author_meta('view_matches') should contain a valid shortcode, by valid i mean..if you insert it in a post it shoudlw ork.

Comment: Yep, I have taken a shortcode out of a normal post that works and put it in there.

Answer (score 1):

[`the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) is going to `echo` content directly. It will not pass a string back that can be processed by `do_shortcode()`.

You want [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta), which is essentially the same as [`the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) but it returns a string instead of `echo`ing the data.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum, I've tried `do_shortcode(get_the_author_meta( 'view_matches' ));` instead and still nothing.  If you go here http://msmr.com.au/my-account/matches/ and use the username leslie-fernando and the password 1234 (yes this is just a dummy subscriber account) you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Then your `view_matches` isn't a valid shortcode or you aren't `echo`ing the output of `do_shortcode()`. It doesn't `echo` by default, but returns a string.

Comment: `view_matches` is the variable/meta name of the textarea in the database though, not the shortcode. I am using another shortcode from the UPME profile plugin.  So instead of using print, use echo?

Comment: The output of `get_the_author_meta( 'view_matches' )` needs to be a valid shortcode just like you'd write into the post body-- `[myshortcode]`. If not this won't work. It shouldn't matter what provides the callback for the shortcode. Either `echo` or `print` should work.

Comment: I think my original question may not have been quite clear. get_the_author_meta('view_matches') is not a shortcode.

What is happening is I have created an additional meta tag in the author section using a textarea field.  Now I want to be able to make that textarea field work like a post/page in WordPress where you can place a shortcode of any type in there and the shortcode will execute.  `view_matches` is the textarea field which has a shortcode in called `[upme]` which will execute in there.  I hope that explains it a bit better.

Comment: The answer doesn't change. If the output of `get_the_author_meta( 'view_matches' )` contains a string with a shortcode in it the shortcode should be processed by `do_shortcode()`.